# What is the exact meaing of the russian?

Tags: перевод

[image]

A friend of russian sent me a book and wrote sth on the last page on it, you know that the russian handwritting is hard to recongnize,would you please tell me the meaning of it please ?

Answer (score 11):

It's '*With best wishes from Dmitry* (*Di-yi-ma* /in Chinese characters/)'. Original text:

> С наилучшими пожеланиями от Дмитрия (迪已马).

Answer (score 3):

Your friend's name is Дмитрий. That's the last word "от Дмитрия". The first two are "С наилучшими пожеланиями от Дмитрия." Since the site doesn't provide translation services, I will stop here. Hope you can find out the meaning.

Answer (score 1):

С наилучшими пожеланиями от Дмитрия  (迪已马)